# How to make a table in html like this

Tags: html, html-table

I want to create a table like this:-

this is just a sample

```
     ______________________________________________________________
    |               |                      |         |            |
    |               |______________________|         |            |
    |               |        |             |         |            |
    |               |________|_____________|         |            |
    |               |           |          |         |            |
    |_______________|___________|__________|_________|____________|
```

Comment: This is as basic as it gets when it come to HTML tables. You can find tutorials about it in a website called "Google".

Comment: how long did it take to type that out... ;-)

Comment: @DaveSumter Sorry, had to google each word as i'm not a native English speaker

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us the effort you made in trying to solve your problem and [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to increase the likelihood of getting your question answered.

Comment: Alon, was referring to the table lines.. ;-)

Comment: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables

Comment: Play around with colspan / rowspan to get the exact sizing you want..  <table> <tr> <th colspan="2" rowspan="3"></th> <th colspan="3"></th> <th rowspan="3"></th> <th colspan="2" rowspan="3"></th> </tr> <tr> <td></td> <td colspan="2"></td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan="2"></td> <td></td> </tr> </table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes.

`rowspan` specifies the number of rows a cell should span. i.e `<td rowspan='2'></td>` specify that the cell should span 2 rows.

`colspan` specifies the number of columns a cell should span. i.e `<td colspan='2'></td>` specify that the cell should span 2 columns.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3"></th>
    <th colspan="5"></th>
    <th rowspan="3"></th>
    <th rowspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2"></td>
     <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks man you save my tons of hours... +1